# pylons/pyramid code completion with gedit and virtualenv

Tags: python, pylons, virtualenv, gedit, pyramid

I am working through the pyramid documentation and would really like code completion. I installed [gedit-plugin-codecompletion](https://github.com/nagaozen/gedit-plugin-codecompletion)

I am using `virtualenv`, once created I use the 'activate' file in the `bin/` folder to switch over my terminal window. When I launch `gedit` I see these errors:

```
(env)agd@hephaestus:~/Dev/projects/LearningPyramid$ gedit 

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Error initializing Python interpreter: could not import pygtk.

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Please check the installation of all the Python related packages required by gedit and try again.

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Cannot load python plugin Python 'Bracket Completion' since gedit wasnot able to initialize the Python interpreter.

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'Bracket Completion'

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Cannot load python plugin Python 'Evolved Code Completion' since gedit wasnot able to initialize the Python interpreter.

** (gedit:11418): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'Evolved Code Completion'
```

Would be very interested in anything you can help me with!

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 2):

You should create your virtualenv *without* `--no-site-packages` argument to allow access to python packages installed system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I just wouldn't run gedit from within your virtualenv.  Start a new terminal window if you must.  It just seems cleaner than installing non-development packages into your virtualenv.

Running without `--no-site-packages` could work, but some people think it's a good idea to keep your virtualenv truly isolated from your system so that you can keep it completely isolated and controlled the no-site-packages option removes that isolation.

Comment: What's with the random downvote?  At least leave a comment to tell why you think the answer isn't helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As a first idea, I'd suggest you to run `pip install pygtk` in your `env` virtualenv. Have you tried it?